# MongoDb Java driver reactive with POJO mapping find List of documents in a type safe way

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, reactive-streams, reactive-mongo-java

I have a bunch of `Document` in a `Collection` and would like to retrieve all of them. This is my situation:

1. I am using the Java Reactive Streams driver
2. I am using the `CodecRegistry` to get my `Document` deserialized to my `Pojo`

The problem is that all flavours of the `find()` method returns a `FindPublisher<Pojo>` and needlessly to say that any kind of value emission will result in the returning of `Pojo` object. **I want a `List<Pojo>` or a `Set<Pojo>` returned. How do I return a `List<Pojo` or a `Set<Pojo>`?**

In the [quickstart](https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/java-mapping-pojos), they are using the `find().first()` which returns a single `Document` and hence a single `Pojo` object makes sense. There is no example for returning multiple `Document`.

Comment: For clarification: Can you show how you are accessing the collection? If I use `database.getCollection("pojos", Pojo.class)`, then I can use `List<Pojo> pojos = new ArrayList<>();` followed by `collection.find().forEach(a -> pojos.add(a));`. This assumes my codec is set up correctly, of course. But my approach uses a `FindIterable` not a `FindPublisher` - so I may be missing the reactive piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @andrewjames I am aware of the `FindIterable` approach. But I am unable to find a `FindPublisher` approach example. If I have to go by the `findIterable` approach and adapt to `findPublisher` then it would be something like `Single.fromPublisher(collection.find()).map(pojo -> list.add(pojo)....)` and then return the `list` somehow. I am following the collection access setup as per the link provided in my question , but with the reactive streams driver.

Answer (score 0):

Using [MongoDB Reactive Streams Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/) and [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), for example:

```
Publisher<Document> publisher = collection.find();
List<Document> docs = Flowable.fromPublisher(publisher)
                              .blockingStream()
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

[EDIT ADD]
You can use a non-blocking call, for example:

```
List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();
Observable.fromPublisher(publisher).subscribe(doc -> docs.add(doc));
```

Comment: First of all, I want to keep it reactive. I don't want to block. That's the entire point of using the reactive streams driver. Secondly, there is no point using a backpressure aware construct like `Flowable` when you are going to block either way. Thirdly, there is no `blockingStream()`  method for `Flowable` instance in RxJava 3.

Comment: (1) You can use a non-blocking methods from the API (2) Method exists [RxJava3 Flowable#blockingStream()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html#blockingStream--) (3) You can use _no backpressure_ [Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html)

Comment: 1. Please refer to the comments below the question to understand the actual issue. If I was getting a `Document` then I would be able to get the objects that I require. But I'm already mapped to a `Pojo` and that's what I get, not a `Document`. 
2. I am using [io.reactivex.Flowable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html) and not the ones that you are using. 
3. Also, please refer to the comments under the question. That will help you get a better picture.

Comment: You can use a Pojo object of your choice instead of a Document.

Comment: My `find()` returns `FindPublisher<Pojo>` and not `FindPublisher<Document>`. That is where I am having problems. Because even a `collection.find()` returns a `FindPublisher<Pojo>`. How am I supposed to interpret this? Also, I am returning something like `Single.fromPublisher(coll.find())....` directly

Comment: _I am using io.reactivex.Flowable and not the ones that you are using._ I think you are using the RxJava 2 APis. The Observable methods I had shown in the examples are the same in both the versions.

Comment: I am using the the latest Micronaut release and they are using RxJava3 there